# aem-6-2-replication-issue-for-node-containing-invalid-jcr-names

Tags: adobe, aem

I am working on AEM 5.6 to 6.2 upgrade project. There are some nodes in aem 5.6 environment which contains invalid character(as per JCR naming convention like rte[2] is one of the node name which doesn't follow the naming convention)but somehow we are able to replicate those nodes in 5.6 environment. After upgrade it to aem 6.2,it seems like JCR is more restricted and won't allow the nodes to replicate if it is having invalid characters. 
Getting the below error in aem 6.2: error: 
**com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationException: Repository error during node import: Cannot create a new node using a name including an index** 
Is there any way we can configure AEM 6.2 to stop checking JCR node names?or any other solution?

Comment: Did you tried package installation of same node filters instead of replication?

Comment: yes i have tried that also...if we directly install the content package in aem 6.2 then it will skip those nodes which is having invalid jcr names.

Comment: Its because of the oak workspace restriction **if (oakName.contains("[")) { throw new RepositoryException("Cannot create a new node using a name including an index"); }** and i don't think you can escape this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCR 2 does not allow `[` as a valid character therefore you won't get an easy workaround for this. It's one of the limitations just like the same-named-sibling.

My recommendation will be to modify these nodes before the upgrade/migration to 6.2. This can be complicated and costly for business but 6.2 won't allow it.

As a background `[` was allowed in older version due to twisted support for grammar syntax for same-named-siblings.

Assuming that these are all content nodes as nothing out-of-the-box in AEM 5.x follows this naming convention.

Some ways to fix it:

1. Write a custom servlet to query and rename the paths across all references. You will have to test your content for these renames.
2. Use Groovy console (https://github.com/OlsonDigital/aem-groovy-console) to rename the nodes.

In either case, you will need to modify the nodes before the migration as the structure is not oak compliant therefore you cannot use crx2oak commit hooks also. This can be done with both in-place upgrade and side-by-side migration. This is similar to the problem with same named siblings that must be corrected before the migration.

**Some efficiency techniques that might help:**

1. Write queries to find invalid node names on top-level nodes like /content/mysite-a, /content/mysite-b etc. Don't run root level queries on /content as it might downgrade to
   traversal and halt the execution.
2. Ensure that all references are updated in same commit. If you are using custom servlet, call session.save() only after updating all the node names and it's corresponding references.

Comment: there are 4000 nodes which contains the '[' character.What will be the best & efficient approach to remove/modify this?

Comment: Updated my response

Comment: Do you have any example of groovy script that can perform this task?that will be really helpful.

Comment: See the sample like JcrQuery in the console and once you have your resultset you can follow the documentation below to rename a node: https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExamplesPage#Renaming_a_Node

Comment: thanks for your help. executed groovy script for this issue and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As i mention in the comment this replication failure causes because of the oak workspace restriction as the code snippet below

`//handle index
if (oakName.contains("["))
{ throw new RepositoryException("Cannot create a new node using a name including an index"); 
}`

and i feel you can't escape this constraint as it it required by the repository to maintain consistency

you can find nodes that ends with **'['**, by below query

```
SELECT [jcr:path] FROM [nt:base] WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE('/content/path/') AND [jcr:path] like '%\['
```

and to modify the JCR/CRX nodes you can use *CURL* or *SlingPostServlet* method

Some helpful posts are blow.

https://github.com/paulrohrbeck/aem-links/blob/master/curl_cheatsheet.md
http://sling.apache.org/site/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servletspost.html

Comment: thanks for your help.Just Wondering if you are aware of the curl command that can rename the node based on the query?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try migrating using a tool like `oak-upgrade` and let us know if you are still facing this issue.

The [tool](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/migration.html) is robust and you have the flexibility to configure specific sub-trees for migration using this tool.

Comment: yes that's what we have done...we have used oak migration tool to upgrade the repository

Comment: After repository upgrade using oak tool we can still see this issue.